# determining function declaration, definition and call

Tags: c++, code-coverage

I came across a question regarding writing a code to determine unused functions in C++. We can use different data structures to determine unused functions. But before that, we need to parse the code. I have question related to parsing part, how we can differentiate functions declaration and definition and function-calls?

Like,

```
 //function declaration without argument
 fun1 ();

 //function definition
 fun1 () {
   // code goes here
  }

 main () {
   fun1 ();
  }
```

Above declaration and call is looks same where as definition part is little bit different from declaration and call.

Other than above scenario, there are multiple scenario for calling a function and functions scope, like two classes having function with same name one function get called within member function (i.e. no explicit calling object required) OR function call using object so, need to understand object's type first to determine which function is actually called.

How can parsing implemented efficiently? How many parsing will required in above scenario?

Comment: I'm not a C++ guru, but don't function declarations and definitions denote the return value type?

Comment: @Adnan Unless you consider `implicit int` that's right. @Sachin Parsing C++ is incredibly hard. I suggest using `libclang` to do the parsing for you and do your static analysis with it instead of trying to do this yourself. This gets incredibly hard with templates.

Comment: Thanks @pmr, I should get involved with C++ a bit more.

Comment: @Adnan Not knowing about `implicit int` is probably a good thing.

Comment: @pmr: IIRC, C++ doesn't allow the implicit `int` return type.

Comment: @Adnan and Marcelo : You are correct. Implicit return type not allowed in C++. basically, I was trying to describe simplest scenario from different scenarios for static parsing like function overriding or virtual functions or function with similar name from different namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can distinguish them:

```
//function definition
return_type fun1 (args) {
  // code goes here
}
```

Note that function definition has a "return type" before the function name.

Also, note that a function declaration looks exactly the same as its definition. You don't actually need to distinguish them until you see either `;` or `{`. That is the point in which you make the decision whether its a declaration or definition. In your particular application, you don't really care about it because you don't care what the function actually does.

Unfortunately for you, C++ is complicated. To determine which functions are useless, you actually need at least a basic semantic analysis. This includes at least the type system.

What is worse, is that some function may not necessarily be called directly, but through a virtual function. So your static analysis of the code shows only the parent's function getting called, while in reality it's the child's.

Comment: This reminds me of Monty Python: "What's the difference between a duck?" In all seriousness, though, are you suggesting that function declarations don't have a return type?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean! Updated my answer.

Comment: @Shahbaz: It looks complicated to determine functions calls using static parsing. If still static parsing is performed, you need to consider its limitation that function overriding and other scenarios wont able to handle. thanks. i think i got it.

Comment: It _is_ complicated. You could make it a bit intelligent with the type system, or a bit of execution (not real execution, but assuming all cases of `if` and `else` have been executed) to get the possible children types a parent can take, but in the end, you could always come up with examples that the algorithm generates false positives (or if it's too restrict, false negatives).